# How do I select several nested instances of a specific element in CSS?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, css-selectors

I want to only select the first two nested `<img/>` elements and set `width: 200px;` or something. How would I select them using combinators instead of giving them their own class?

I've tried using `nth-child(-n+2)`, but since each `<img/>` is nested in a different `<div>`, I think it is trying to select the first two instances of `<img/>` in every `<div>` instead of the first two instances of `<img/>` within the `<section>`. I'm still learning about combinators, so an explanation of the answer would be greatly appreciated.

My code looks something like this:

```css
.section-container div {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

.section-container div img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <header>
      <!--Navbar stuff-->
      <h1>I'm the navbar</h1>
   </header>
   <section class="section-container">
      <h2>subheading</h2>
      <div>
         <img src="image 1"/>
         <p>1st div</p>
      </div>

      <div>
         <img src="image 2"/>
         <p>2nd div</p>
      </div>

      <div>
         <img src="image 3"/>
         <p>3rd div</p>
      </div>

      <div>
         <img src="image 4"/>
         <p>4th div</p>
      </div>
   </section>
   <form>
      <h2>Form</h2>
      <label for"name-input">Name*</label>
      <input id="name-input" type="text"></input>
      <button>Submit</button>
   </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply nth-child on actual siblings since the `img` tags are not directly related to one another.

```
.section-container div:nth-child(-n+2) img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: This solution worked, however I had to use (-n+3) to select the first two images for some reason, (-n+2) was only selecting the first image.

Comment: @EthanPartridge https://jsfiddle.net/Lt8jw9vf/ for me it works with -n+2. Is the structure of your actual code different from this?

Comment: I edited my question to better reflect my code. I'm using asp.net mvc, so the header is not actually contained in this actual html page, but is in a shared layout page shared by all pages in my web application. I went ahead and included it in this example just in case.

Comment: The `<h2>subheading</h2>` is the cause of that.

Comment: Ah, I see. When I use ```.section-container div:nth-of-type(-n+2) img``` instead, it selects the first two images since nth-of-type is more specific I'm assuming. Thank you

Comment: Yes. `nth-child(-n+2)` does not look for the first or second `div` respectively, but for a `div` that is a first or second child.